# Maven war:war with restriction

Tags: java, maven

When I issue mvn war:war, I want only war file to be created. No need of exploded project folder under the target folder. How to restrict this?

mvn war:war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "exploded project folder" is not there for your viewing convenience - it looks like that because of [how the Maven build lifecycle is constructed](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

A Maven build runs a sequence of *phases*, and plugin *goals* executed in later phases have expectations regarding what they will find in the `target` folder - that's the one where the build process takes place.

So, for example, the [`war:war` goal is bound to the `package` phase](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html).

Previous to that there is the `compile` phase, where the `maven-compiler-plugin` will run. And that's how your compiled Java classes end up in your `WAR` - they get compiled to `.class` files into a subdirectory of `target`, and then, later, the `war` plugin picks them up and packages them into the `WAR`.

The only way to achieve your desired result would be to add an `antrun` task or similar that would **delete everything but the `WAR`, *after* the `WAR` is packaged**.

But this **is a bad idea**. If you still don't know why, consider the following:

- what happens if you extend your build to include something else after the `war` goal (say, in `verify`), that expects the build's transitory artifacts remaining present in `target`? Or, even better, use a goal like [`jetty:run-exploded`](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#running-assembled-webapp-as-expanded-war) which **requires** those files?
- what happens if your IDE depends on some of those files for correct processing of your project?